# Insert into Oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to ad column by using subquery.

```
Insert into Table_name
values (1, 'a', 'b', sysdate, sysdate + 120, 'c',
        (Select number from other_table where column_name = 'x'), 2);
```

Error:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Depends on the `number` column. Please share some sample data.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` here.  Note that generally you should always specify the target columns.

```sql
INSERT INTO Table_name (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8)
SELECT 1, 'a', 'b', sysdate, sysdate + 120, 'c', number, 2
FROM other_table
WHERE column_name = 'x';
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to force a single row

note the extra "ROWNUM" below

something like:

```
Insert into Table_name values(1,'a','b',sysdate,sysdate + 120,'c',(Select number from other_table where column_name = 'x' and ROWNUM = 1),2);
```

see:https://blogs.oracle.com/connect/post/on-rownum-and-limiting-results

Comment: Just getting the top one would not be the best idea, maybe the answer is to limit it on another `where` condition.

Comment: sorry. it should be where/and, instead of 2 wheres.

Comment: This query will not resolve the issue, but just remove an error. Because it will return an arbitrary row and will never fail even in case of change in the data model, making it hard to locate the problematic code.

Comment: Then your where clause on your "inner-select" needs to be more specific.  If you are trying to find a specific ROW with your "inner-select" you need to add more information in your question.